# SQL Server: Select Max for each sub group in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am new to **SQL Server**. I have a table that contains user names, addresses and the update dates.

The following query gives me all required details from that table but my problem is that the table can contain multiple records for the same user / ID in case they changed their address more than once.

How can I **only get the address from the latest update for each user / ID**?  I tried with `DISTINCT`, `TOP1` etc. but couldn't figure out a way to make this work.

**My query:**

```
SELECT
    u.ID
    , u.lastName + ', ' + u.firstName AS fullName
    , u.DOB
    , u.homeAddress
    , u.updateDate AS lastUpdate
FROM dbo.Users u
GROUP BY u.ID, u.lastName, u.firstName, u.homeAddress, u.updateDate
ORDER BY u.lastName, u.firstName, updateDate DESC
```

Comment: Study the `row_number() over(partition by ...)` construct, there are literally hundreds of examples in StackOverflow and thousands elsewhere.

Comment: ... and I just added another one by posting an answer to your question! Window functions are very important, **ANSI** sql (I think only MySql still lacks support of them among all major RDBMSs), so I suggest you try to master them.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis: at least MariaDB will finally arrive in the 21st century once 10.2 is released: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/AEF99242)

```
select * from (
select rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by updateDate desc), *
from Users
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well !

Comment: You are welcome, take care! [And keep in mind that this is the standard approach since SQL Server 2005 :-) ]

Comment: I played around with this and got both this and Carlos' approach to work. I ended up deciding for the more intuitive approach which is just because I find it easier to write and to apply in my mind - no evaluation. :) Thanks for both !

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do in an more intuitive old style fashion, just with a subselect:

```
SELECT
    u.ID
    , u.lastName + ', ' + u.firstName AS fullName
    , u.DOB
    , u.homeAddress
    , u.updateDate AS lastUpdate
FROM dbo.Users u INNER JOIN
(
    -- here is where we get the last update
    select u.ID, max(u.updateDate) as lastUpdate from dbo.Users group by u.ID
) as s
on u.ID = s.ID
-- and here we force the address of the last update
WHERE u.updateDate = s.lastUpdate 
GROUP BY u.ID, u.lastName, u.firstName, u.homeAddress, u.updateDate
ORDER BY u.lastName, u.firstName, updateDate DESC
```

You get the last update of each ID in a subselect, and filter this date in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the quick reply ! :)

Comment: It certainly works, it certainly is old-fashioned :-), but I think it is anything but  intuitive!

Comment: I played around with this and got both this and Giorgos' approach to work. I ended up deciding for the more intuitive approach which is just because I find it easier to write and to apply in my mind - no evaluation. :) Thanks for both !

Comment: @Mike it is certainly not an evaluation issue, actually trying both approaches and deciding what fits you best is a very good habit. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Go with `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  u.ID ORDER BY u.updateDate DESC ) AS SNO
    , u.ID
    , u.lastName + ', ' + u.firstName AS fullName
    , u.DOB
    , u.homeAddress
    , u.updateDate AS lastUpdate
    FROM dbo.Users u
)A
WHERE A.SNO=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **(1)** Group your user ID; **(2)** sort descending your updateDate and **(3)** `DISTINCT` your user ID as below:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT u.ID
    , u.lastName + ', ' + u.firstName AS fullName
    , u.DOB
    , u.homeAddress
    , u.updateDate AS lastUpdate
FROM dbo.Users u
GROUP BY u.ID
ORDER BY u.updateDate DESC
```